# General term for map/fmap

Tags: functional-programming

The general term for folds is a catamorphism. The general term for unfold is an Anamorphism. Is there an equivalent term for map?  I know that a map is a type of fold however restriction is significant.  Also it would be useful to have an alternative term to use when the word “map” is ambiguous.

Comment: I strongly recommend against the "catamorphism/anamorphism/etc" terminology. "Fold/unfold" is perfectly fine for the "general" case and more likely to be understood. At any rate, if someone doesn't know what "fold/unfold" is (given suitable context), they are unlikely to recognize "catamorophism/anamorphism".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to being in agreement with Derek (that the ana/cata terminology doesn't bring much to the table) I'll note that the "category theoretic" terminology for the general `map` function of type
$$\mathrm{map}:\forall \alpha\beta. (\alpha \rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow(F\ \alpha\rightarrow F\beta) $$
for a functor $F$ is simply "the functorial action of $F$", and is often written as $F$! For example, on lists, `map f l` would be written $\mathrm{List}(f)(l)$.

For some reason, computer scientists seem to prefer to have a seperate name for the type constructor and the action on morphisms, but mathematicians do not really consider non-functorial constructors anyways.

Comment: Just for clarification the “!” Isnt’ a part of the notation?

Comment: @QthePlatypus No it is not. Good question.

Comment: A separate symbol for the action of a functor on morphisms is needed rather in formal (including programming) languages than in computer science. The natural mathematical language has ambiguities which are inconvenient in a formal language.

Answer (score 1):

I think `fmap`, at least in the context of Haskell, is already the general term for the thing it does and the thing you're talking about.

The fact that a `map` function also exists, which is basically an `fmap` that only works on lists, is mostly a historical accident AFAIK.

Perhaps you're looking for the word `Functor`, being the thing that has an `fmap`?